# Getting an error with SQL Query Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting this error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a sub-query

Below is part of my SQL query_

```
SUM((CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT [Amount] FROM [Transaction_table] 
              WHERE [Receipt No_] = se.[Receipt No_]) IS NULL
           THEN 1 
           ELSE [Amount] 
     END)) 'Total Amount'
```

Comment: show your full statement

Answer (score 1):

I think ANSI sql standard `coalesce()` will do that you want

```
select sum(coalesce([Amount],1)) [Total Amount] from [Transaction_table]
where [Receipt No_]=se.[Receipt No_]
```

other way by `case` expression will do the same thing

```
select sum(case when [Amount] is null then 1 else [Amount] end) [Total Amount]
from [Transaction_table]
where [Receipt  No_] = se.[Receipt No_];
```